# How to set a different timezone without changing the time

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

Given a moment time, how do you change the timezone without changing the actual time?

For example if you have `2020-06-19 16:30:00+00` but you want this in `America/New_York` timezone.

The output would be `2020-06-19 16:30:00-04:00` (currently Daylight Savings time).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `.tz(.., true)` function.

From the Moment Timezone docs (https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/):

> On passing a second parameter as true, only the timezone (and offset) is updated, keeping the local time same. Consequently, it will now point to a different point in time if the offset has changed.
>
> ```
> m.format();                           // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00
> m.tz('Europe/Berlin', true).format()  // 2013-11-18T11:55:00+01:00
> ```